# Can't depress clutch

Tags: clutch, subaru, wrx

Bought my first rexy back in december, it's a 2012 WRX. Couple of days ago the clutch pedal wouldn't spring back up. I've googled around and some say it could be the clutch master or slave cylinder.

checked my slave cylinder and there was some leakage. Took the slave out and took the seal apart. Lo and behold the metal inside had cracked. Bought a second hand slave cylinder from a subie wrecker. Replaced it and bled the system.

The issue I have now is the clutch pedal is very stiff and won't depress(probably 1/3 of the way). It can even go into gear without depressing the clutch while the car is on, and it doesn't stall.

Any idea what is happening?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Can you take the slave down from the transmission and see what it's doing? Have someone else press the clutch pedal while you observe. If it's still stiff to press, the slave is a bad 2nd hand unit. Since you can put it in gear without the pedal pushed, it sounds like the slave is stuck in the out position (or where it would normally disengage the clutch). If so, it could be bad in that aspect as well.

Comment: Thanks for the resppnse - ill do that once i get home. I asked a family member to check the clutch fork and he said that the fork is away from the slave cylinder. Normally the fork should be resting on the slave cylinder?

Comment: Yah, that seems kinda screwy. I don't know if that's a clutch issue or a master/slave issue (or both).